# Smartgit Clonning Repo from gitlab SSH authentication error

Tags: ssh, gitlab, git-clone, smartgit

Although I have assigned my public key to my gitLab account and used my private key. It still says "Exhausted available authentication methods". When I try to clone repository from gitlab.
[image]

When I cancel it, there are missing files in the cloned repo.
(I can clone other repositories from my gitlab but only with thisone I experience the issue)

Answer (score 0):

This happens when there is a mismatch between some settings of the SSH client and the SSH server.  One of the encryption settings changed switches a year or so ago and caused problems.  SmartGit's internal SSH is a little older, I think, so it has problems talking to new git servers sometimes.  Try using your "System SSH" and upgrade to a new version of SSH on your machine.  You can set your private keys inside a `config` file in your user/.ssh folder to control how it connects.  Worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I would select "private key" and copy a private key generated without passphrase protection, to simplify the process.

Using a password (not passphrase) would mean using a username/password, which is not allowed for any Git remote repository hosting service (GitHub, GitLab, ...)